# CakePHP 2.x: How can I overwrite an URL pointing to the index page?

Tags: url, cakephp, indexing, routes, cakephp-2.x

I'm getting this issue:

```
Router::connect('/',array('controller' => 'Controller','action' => 'login'));
```

This will show `www.mysite/controller/login` as the site URL

I would like to overwrite `www.mysite.com/controller/login` with just `www.mysite.com`, but still go to the login page. Does anyone know how to do it with Cake 2.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior It's not exactly as you describe.

What the following does:

```
Router::connect('/',array('controller' => 'Controller','action' => 'login'));
```

is allow you to type `www.mysite.com`   in your browser, and get the view that `www.mysite.com/controller/login` renders.

It works like an **url rewrite** instead of a redirect. Therefore, the above should work as expected. However, if it's not an example, try to name your controller differently, as it may cause trouble with CakePHP.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how can I do the url rewrite?

Comment: As stated, the URL rewrite is the default. If you need a redirect, you call `$this->redirect()` in your actions.

Comment: I don't need a redirect. I just need to "hide" the "/controller/login" from the URL bar without using any JS

Comment: I'm really sorry I have no experience at all with this framework and I really don't see how it is already done :( I don't know if you understand what I want to do. I don't know if I had to add a RewriteRule in my .htaccess ... I'm really lost

Comment: Don't worry :) With the above, If you call `www.mysite.com/`, you should see the login page, and the URL will not change.

Comment: my problem must be elsewhere then. As soon as I type `www.mysite.com/` and hit enter my URL bar shows `www.mysite.com/controller/login`

Comment: if you have loaded the `Auth` component, this could possibly be the cause

Comment: Then that's the expected behavior. You can modify `loginAction` to point to `/`. See the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Inigo `Router::connect()` just connects a route/URL to a controller action. So with your defined route you should be able to goto `www.mysite.com` and your login action will be served (although I'm not sure that it is a good idea to have the base URL act as the login page).

It does not prevent `www.mysite.com/controller/login` from working as this is one of CakePHP's default routes.

To disable the default routes you need to remove this line from `routes.php`:-

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Be warned, if you remove this line you must have defined routes for all your pages in your app's routes file. This is not necessarily a bad thing, [Beware the Route to Evil](https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2013/07/23/beware-the-route-to-evil/) is a good read in regards to this.

Answer (score 0):

As I used the "Auth" component I had to add in the function

`beforeFilter()`

of my controller this line:

`$this->Auth->allow('anAction', 'anotherAction', '**login**');`